# Navigation PushAsync MAUI C# not go to other Pages

Tags: c#, maui

good day
i try multuble time but when i press button will not go to fluid page now 3h try find sloution but not found MAUI C# i try Navigation.popAsync i know its for going back but not work , i try make debug on mathod  private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) it reach her after i make continue so it will go to Navigation.PushAsync but pixal android emelator  crash

XAML MainPage

```
<ScrollView>

            <Grid x:Name="Container" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" RowDefinitions="100,70,300,90,90,90,250" ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*,*" Margin="0,0,0,10">

                <Frame  VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Secondary}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" HeightRequest="90">

                    <Label Text="مركز إصلاح واجن لصيانة السيارات " FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />

                </Frame>

                <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Margin="0,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TextColor}">

                <Label Text="menu" FontSize="Large" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HeightRequest="70" Margin="0,5,0,5" />

                 </Frame>

                <Frame Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Secondary}" Margin="0,5,0,5" >

                    <Label Text="pic slider" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

                </Frame>

    
                   <Button Text="تغيير الزيوت "   BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="170" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
                   <Button Text="تغيير الإطارات "  BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="170" />
                   <Button Text="تغيير البطارية " BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="170"/>
                   <Button Text="الصيانة الدورية" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="170"/>
                   <Button Text="الصيانات الاخرى " BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center"  Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="170"/>
                   <Button Text="test"            BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center"  Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="170"/>


            <Frame Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Secondary}">

                <Label Text="footer" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

            </Frame>
                
                
             </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
```

C# MainPage

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Fluid());
    }
}
```

i want go to page fluid

this work thanks guys

To make MainPage a NavigationPage, you can modify the App.xaml.cs file. Here are the steps:

Open the App.xaml.cs file in your project.
In the OnStart method, create a new instance of the MainPage and wrap it in a NavigationPage.
Set the MainPage property of the App class to the new NavigationPage.
Here’s an example of what the modified code might look like:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create a new NavigationPage with MainPage as the root page
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }

    
}
```

With this modification, MainPage will now be displayed as the root page of a NavigationPage, which will allow you to navigate to other pages using the Navigation.PushAsync method.

Comment: to use `Navigation.PushAsync` your `MainPage` needs to be contained in a `NavigationPage`

Comment: see maui shell navigation doc, for correct method to call.

Comment: Please consider answering it as an answer rather than editing the question itself. It might help future people who's having same question

Comment: You may refer to [NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage?view=net-maui-7.0) for more info. And your solution deserves an answer.